# Is the Matrix trilogy inspired by Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-matrix

It is well known that the Wachowskis' trilogy was inspired by several aspects of philosophy, science and popular culture. Watching *The Matrix* trilogy, I could see some details that led me to question whether this saga also was inspired by the space opera of George Lucas. For example, Morpheus' attachment to *Nebuchadnezzar* reminded me a lot of Han Solo and the *Millenium Falcon* (even the interiors of the ships are similar). Futhermore, the final battle in *The Matrix Revolutions* reminded me the rebels against the Empire in several scenes. Would anyone know of any source that proves the *Star Wars*' influence on *The Matrix*?

Comment: Without specifics what you’ve mentioned here are things that are quite tropey. There’s no reason to believe one inspired the other just from those two points.

Comment: **Q.** *What do you think about star wars?* **WachowskiBros:** *It was one of the first films that we went berserk over when we were kids.*

Comment: @Valorum, Interesting! Where can I find this information?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, I understand, although these were just a few examples. I noticed that in several ship and robot combat scenes, there is a certain resemblance to scenes I saw in Star Wars films (but I may be mistaken, of course).

Comment: @ArthurFilipe - https://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix/wachowski-brothers-chat-transcript/

Comment: @Valorum, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wachowski sisters did specifically cite George Lucas as one of the filmmakers they watched while preparing to make *The Matrix* in a 1999 interview with the New York Times, though no mention was made of *Star Wars* specifically.

> [They] studied the work of directors as varied as John Woo and other Hong Kong filmmakers, Stanley Kubrick, John Huston, Billy Wilder, Ridley Scott, George Lucas and Fritz Lang. They also read and reread their favorite book, ''The Odyssey.''
>
> [-*New York Times*, April 5 1999](https://www.nytimes.com/1999/04/05/movies/brothers-unleash-the-comic-book-of-ideas.html)

Comment: Very cool to know this!